# Problem copying some .dylibs into my bundle iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dylib

So I'm developing an app that uses some .dylibs. I have added them all into my Bundle Phases like this:

[image]

The problem that I am having is that, when I archive the app so I can generate a bundle, not all of the dylibs are copying and it shows me this error on 3 of the dylibs that I have:

```
error: /Users/edwardpizzurro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Radio_Cash-cvgyuqrqihnqmmdkqltlhiouqdct/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Radio Cash/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libfftw3f.3.6.9.dylib: No such file or directory
```

When I run the app on Xcode on my device, it works fine, the problem occurs when I try to archive the app.